# Read a file in a fragment and put it in a listview

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a "Todo.txt" file where i want to read all lines and insert them to my listview. It seems like the listview is not getting any items and the problem is how i read the file in. Any suggestions?

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {
    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        // Set title of fragment page
        TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.titleTextView);
        textView.setText(getArguments().getString("fragmentTitle"));

        ListView listView = (ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.listview);

        arrayListSetup();

        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                arrayList
        );

        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        return v;
    }

    private void arrayListSetup(){
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new MainActivity().FILENAME));
            String line;

            // add line to arraylist
            while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
                arrayList.add(line);
            }
            // close bufferedreader
            br.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The MainActivity when clicking the button, it writes the todo-activity to the file:

```
addTodoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // Get category of to-do
                String category = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

                // Get the to-do text what has to be done
                String todo_text = editText.getText().toString();


                // Try to create inputfile
                try {
                    FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    fos.write(todo_text.getBytes());
                    fos.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that i didnt call `getActivity()` before calling `openFileInput()`,  because a Fragment is not a context!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should call the function `arrayListSetup()` in your fragment's `onCreateView()`
You have declared your arraylist but haven't populated it by calling the `arraylistsetup()` function, call it in the `onCreateView()`

Comment: i forgot it somehow. I added it, but its still not working.

Comment: Can you upload the changed code ? To show where you have called the function

Comment: i added it see above first code part. after creating "listView"